# offset inside a for statment

Tags: python, for-loop, element, offset

I having been trying to offset inside a for statement so i can evaluate changes in the data sequence. Wondering what i am doing wrong here. maybe to for statement isn't the best method, so tried using next inside an if statement as well. this will be used large data sets.

```
n = 1
data = [10,9,8,7,6,5,6,7,8,7,6]

def test(data,n):
    highs = []
    for d in data:
        if d > d[-n]:
            highs.extend([d])
    return highs


def test1(data,n):
    highs = []
    if data[n+1] > data[n]:
        highs.extend([data[n]])
        next
    else:
        next
    return highs
```

can anyone help with what is missing in this? thanks

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: what do you think `next` does?

Comment: `if d > d[-n]:` should this be `if d > data[n]:`? on `test()`

Comment: As a followup to shx2's point, the docs will _tell_ you what [`next`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) does.

Comment: And as a side note, `highs.extend([d])` is the same as `highs.append(d)`. No need to over-complicated things.

Comment: Can you explain better what you want?

Comment: @PauloScardine: I'm not sure what you mean there, but since `d` is always an `int`, _none_ of those things will do anything but raise a `TypeError`.

Comment: @abarnert: comment fixed.

Comment: If you fix `test` to use `data[-n]` instead of `d[-n]` as @FelixCastor suggests, does it produce the right output (e.g., `test(data, 3)` returns `[10, 9]`, because `data[-3] == 8` and those are the only numbers higher than `8`)? If so, what are you trying to "improve" here, and why? If not, what _do_ you want?

Comment: I'm under the impression that `data[-n]` will not work for `n > len(data)` and `data[n+1]` will not work for the range `data[-n:]`.

Comment: @PauloScardine: Yeah, that will raise an `IndexError`, but… so what? If his code does something sensible for `n=1` and `n=3` and `n=9` and raises a meaningful exception for `n=-30` or `n=103`, where's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear as to what you mean by `d[-n]` or `data[n]`.  But I'm guessing you mean the previous value in the list (or the current position - n back).

Here's a simple solution to the problem of finding elements that are larger than the previous one.  Just save that previous value in a variable.

```
prev = data[0] 
highs = [prev] # should the 1st one be one the list?
for d in data:
    if d > prev:
        highs.append(d) # simpler than extend([d])
    prev = d  # update prev       
highs
# [10, 6, 7, 8]
```

Another approach is to step the index

```
for i in range(n, len(data)):
    if data[i]>data[i-n]
        ...
```

Or use `enumerate` to get the index

```
for i, d in enumerate(data):
    j = i - n
    if j>=0:
        if d > data[j]:
           ....
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a sliding window that moves over your data, so you can compare each element to one n before it?

You can use a collections.deque (http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#deque-objects) for this:

```
from itertools import islice
from collections import deque
def windowed(items, size):
    items = iter(items)
    window = deque(islice(items, size), maxlen=size)
    while True:
        yield window
        window.append(items.next())
```

(Using maxlen means that the append pushes the leftmost element out of the fixed-size deque.)

Then you can use it to look at the first and last items in the window with:

```
for window in windowed(data, n):
    # do something with window[0] and window[-1]
```

Access to each end of the deque is quick - O(1).